# Store and access multiple values in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

I am searching an easy and elegant way to keep several `string` and access it the same easy way in winforms application.

I have 10 string variables which I am using in one form, every time I make some change, pressing a button or any other action I need to renew those values.

Here it is the code how I am filling those variables with data:

```
string cDir = clientsbox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
string ClientPath = PMFunc.XMLDir(settings) + cDir;
string ProjectPath = PMFunc.XMLDir(settings) + cDir + @"\"
                     + outlookGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string pathString = Path.Combine(ProjectPath);
string path3DString = Path.Combine(ProjectPath + @"\02-3D");
string pathDatosString = Path.Combine(ProjectPath + @"\01-Datos");
string pathImagenesString = Path.Combine(ProjectPath + @"\03-Imagenes");
string pathProcesso3D = Path.Combine(ProjectPath + @"\02-3D\Processo");
string pathTrafico3D = Path.Combine(ProjectPath + @"\02-3D\Trafico");
string maxfilename = path3DString + @"\" + clientsbox2.SelectedItem.ToString() 
                    + @"-" + PMFunc.ReturnWipNumber(cDir,
                    outlookGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToString(),
                    outlookGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ToString()) + @"-"
                    + outlookGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + @"-"
                    + PMFunc.ReturnCopyNumber(cDir,
                    outlookGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToString(),
                    outlookGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ToString()) + @".max";
```

As you can see some of it is being generated by some objects from the Form, and some are being filled by methods from `PMFunc` class which I have in separate file.

So every time I need to fill these variables I am using this block of code, but I am sure there is a way to do that easier.

Can you advice me please?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with executing the same code repeatedly when the requirements call for it.  The only thing that would be wrong is copy/pasting this code repeatedly.  If it's not a function, make it a function, and call the function whenever you need it - that way you can call it as many times you want, while only writing it once.

Comment: you mean just to encapsulate that in a separate method ? If yes - how then i can access the data ? It should look like separate class with these variables declared, but i cannot access forms elements from separate class.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu yes and you should stop using `@"\"` since you already know of `Path.Combine` and you don't need `@` here `"-"`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but still i cannot use this block as a method , as i need all these values not just filled but being able to be accessed later on.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu Just add a method to your form.  All the data is already accessible to you, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it via a copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to make these variables into form properties with getters that read the component values.

```
public string cdir
{
    get
    {
       return clientsbox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}

... etc
```

Comment: sorry but i did not understand that... You mean that by accessing cdir later (if i will add your block of code) it will evaluate the get{} block ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. This is called deferred execution, when you access this property it executes the getter at that time.

Comment: I think Tim would answer Yes. Essentially you will define a Property or write a Function() for each variable you've listed. Given you access form controls the props/funcs would need to be on each form.

Comment: Thanks so much that was exactly what i was looking for ! Those are the minuses when you are learning language by yourself without a teacher.. you can miss such basic things.